# How do I make this UI design in Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I'm making a simple Flutter application that has a bunch of rounded-icon buttons that display in a single row until there is no more space, the rest of the buttons are then displayed in the next row until there is no more space and so on.

However I couldn't find a proper way to structure the widgets. (Still new to flutter)

Here's the result I am looking for: (Should support both device orientations)

[image: Some funny sketch]

A real example:

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.blue[700]),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("App Header"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Text("No idea how I should structure the icons/buttons"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The title is not that great, but I didn't know what to call this design.

Comment: you can use a `GridView`

Comment: Use an OrientationBuilder to change the number of columns. [Sample](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/orientation#2-use-an-orientationbuilder-to-change-the-number-of-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Gridview()`

please take look- [Here is a example code](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/grid-lists)

I create a demo for you

[image]

**And you can also copy my code**

Here is my code-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Help from Abir"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
          return GridView.count(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            crossAxisCount: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 3 : 5,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                      iconSize: 60,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("Item")
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                      iconSize: 60,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("Item")
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                      iconSize: 60,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("Item")
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                      iconSize: 60,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("Item")
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                      iconSize: 60,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("Item")
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                      iconSize: 60,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("Item")
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                      iconSize: 60,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("Item")
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                      iconSize: 60,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("Item")
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                      iconSize: 60,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("Item")
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                      iconSize: 60,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("Item")
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                      iconSize: 60,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("Item")
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.amber,
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                      iconSize: 60,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text("Item")
                ],
              ),
            ],
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: Welcome. I also am glad to help you